# (Rails) Twitter Bootstrap (responsive) using bootstrap-sass horizontal scroll issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using bootstrap-sass to integrate Twitter Bootstrap in Rails but I'm having issues with the browser horizontal scrollbar showing without the need for it.

Sample code in a Rails View:

```
<div class="row-fluid">
  <div class="span4"> &nbsp; </div>
    <div class="span8">
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td><%= image_tag("up-arrow.jpg") %></td>
          <td><h3>&nbsp;&nbsp; Select a Maintenance category </h3></td>
        </tr>
      </table><br>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I can't find why it does it and how to fix it.

See these links examples: http://d.pr/hLQd and http://d.pr/LOOP (Look at the bottom horizontal scroll)

Comment: Why do you have the first 2 lines? They don't close and appear redundant.

Comment: Edited question to answer Jesse.  BTW, I removed the 1st lines and it didn't change anything (they were closed later in the code but since they aren't required, I removed them anyway).

Comment: FYI, this partial gets called from a page and resides within a <div class="container-fluid"> ..

Comment: I think we're going to need to see the HMTL/CSS -- can you post to jslint or a working version to heroku?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed this particular issue by overwriting the `gridGutterWidth` value from 20px (default) to 30 or 35px.
Don't think it's a Bootstrap bug though.
Thanks!